# TypeGraphQL use TypeORM's findAndCount method

Tags: typescript, pagination, typeorm, typegraphql

I would like to use [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io)'s `findAndCount` function which returns `Promise<[Entity[], number]>` for pagination. So I have a resolver:

```
offers(@Arg('page', { defaultValue: 1 }) page: number): Promise<[Offer[], number]> {
    const COUNT = 10
    return this.offerRepository.findAndCount({ take: COUNT, skip: (page - 1) * COUNT })
}
```

I'm also using [type-graphql](https://typegraphql.ml) and want to annotate this resolver with `Query` annotation like so:

```
@Query(returns => ???)
```

However I can't figure out the return type, I tried this (which of course didn't work, because of what `findAndCount` returns):

```
@ObjectType()
class TestType {
    @Field(type => [Offer])
    offers: Offer[]

    @Field()
    count: number
}
```

And tried using it like this: `@Query(returns => [TestType])` and this `@Query(returns => TestType)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't support tuples, so you need to create a response object type:

```
@ObjectType()
class OffersResponse {
  @Field(type => [Offer])
  items: Offer[]

  @Field(type => Int)
  totalCount: number
}
```

And then manually map the tuple to the object:

```
@Query(returns => OffersResponse)
offers(@Arg('page', { defaultValue: 1 }) page: number): Promise<OffersResponse> {
    const COUNT = 10
    const [items, totalCount] = await this.offerRepository.findAndCount(
      { take: COUNT, skip: (page - 1) * COUNT }
    )
    return { items, totalCount }

}
```